# Does anybody know the rationale behind "(nil < 0) == true" and "(nil <= 0) == true" in Swift?

Tags: swift, null, swift2

I think that Swift is a very well constructed modern language, however, there is one thing that puzzle me, and that is the rationale for having **(nil <= 0) == true** and **(nil < 0) == true.**

Here are more cases:

[image]

Anyway, return true for nil < 0 seems to go against the whole optional concept, where one of the argument was about avoiding the default number initialization to "0". Now "0" is special again.

Anybody has any explanation Swift decided to have (nil <= 0) and (nil < 0) return true.

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with 0, per say. Put in any number and (nil <= n) == true will always be true. Since Swift is a more functional based language, nil needs to be SOME sort of value, and it seems they chose it to represent negative infinity (when comparing it to an int), whereas in Objective-C, if you try the same things, you see that nil is actually equal to 0. So it doesn't actually have the default initialization to 0.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Optionals are comparable, so they can be sorted, for example. The rules are very simple:

1. Any two optionals that are nil compare equal.
2. If one of the optionals is nil and the other is not, nil is less than non-nil.
3. If both optionals are not nil, then the unwrapped values are compared.

As a consequence, nil equals nil, and nil is less than any non-nil optional.

It has nothing to do with the value 0 that you assigned. Assign -1000, or +100, or whatever you like, and you get the same result.

Comment: Very smart, this is the reason. I am mad at myself for not thinking of this.

Comment: You can use the nil coalescing operator with optional chaining to get around it and still enjoy the nifty swifty shorthand e.g. 
`let isZoomed = (view as? MetalView)?.cameraPosition.z ?? 0.0 < 0.0`. 
Nearing the limits of readability though.

Comment: `nil == nil` generates an syntax error in Playgrounds and in a .swift program. This is with Xcode 7.3.1.

Comment: I came to this issue when looking at conditional expressions like `instance?.value > 0` and `instance?.value < 0`. If instance is nil, then `(instance?.value < 0) == true` but `(instance?.value > 0) == false` and `(instance?.value == 0) == false` which seems really odd to me.

Comment: Does anyone have a reference to where "Optionals are comparable" is stated by Apple? A pointer to some library code or documentation where they say Optional types all abide by the Comparable protocol is what I'm looking for.

Comment: I just wrote up a blog discussion on some of these issues. See http://www.spasticmuffin.biz/blog/2016/05/19/gotcha-comparison-operators-and-optional-chaining-in-swift/

Answer (score 3):

When comparing two optionals when one is nil and the other some value, the value is always 'bigger' because there isn't nothing.

So

```
nil < 0 = true     Because 0 is some value but nil isn't
nil == 0 = false    Makes sense because 0 isn't nil
nil <= 0 = true    Same as before
```

0 can also be replaced with any value and the same result would be produced. Actually the function

```
func < <T>(lhs: T?, rhs: T?) -> Bool
```

Doesn't even look at the underlying value if one of them is nil, it just says: **Some value is bigger than no value** and **No value is equal to no value**

Comment: yes, you are right. Should have looked at the code.